# Checking implicit rule predicate in Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, predicate

I hope I've used an understandable title. What I want to achieve is prolog to determine a relation even though it isn't explicitly stated.

```
brother(anders, jason).
sister(anders, madonna).
siblings(X,Y) :- sister(X,Y).
siblings(X,Y) :- brother(X,Y).
siblings(X,Y) :- siblings(X,Z), siblings(Z,Y).
```

It's the sibling rule I'm struggling with. Clearly Jason is Anders brother, and Madonna is Anders sister. Jason and Madonna is therefor Anders' siblings. They are also siblings with each other even though this isn't explicitly stated. How do I make prolog determine this by checking the siblings of a sibling? It's my last rule that will cause a stack overflow \o/ which really isn't that much of a surprise. Is this achievable in a recursive fashion or do I need to write more rules like:

```
siblings(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), brother(Z,Y).
siblings(X,Y) :- sister(X,Z), sister(Z,Y).
siblings(X,Y) :- brother(X,Z), sister(Z,Y).
siblings(X,Y) :- brother(X,Z), brother(Z,Y).
```

The above would not work if we had a very large family and even bigger gaps in our brother/sister facts, that could mean that I have to check if a person is sibling to my siblings sibling and so on.

It might not be a good real world example but I'm looking for the concept of handling these situation rather than a solution to a specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might work automatically in a Prolog with tabling (YAP or XB) given the appropriate annotation, but most of us live within the limitations of standard-ish Prolog. Your additional rules are really just pushing food around on your plate. You can see you would need ever more of them to handle a situation like this:

```
brother(anders, brian).
brother(celeste, donal).
sister(brian, celeste).
```

If you want `sibling(anders, X)` to ever unify X with `donal` you're going to need a bigger boat.

Let's call this your recursive rule:

```
siblings(X,Y) :- siblings(X,Z), siblings(Z,Y).
```

This can't ever succeed, because in order to succeed, it must first succeed. The stack overflow isn't happening because you're calling `siblings/2` recursively, it's happening because it calls it twice to fulfill it once. It spends two dollars to earn one. But you can break even by spending what you make, by replacing that rule with this:

```
siblings(X, Z) :- brother(X, Y), siblings(Y, Z).
siblings(X, Z) :- sister(X, Y),  siblings(Y, Z).
```

This is a capital improvement, but it isn't enough. This basically gets us directed siblinghood. Brian is Anders's brother, but Anders isn't Brian's brother. The problem is severe enough that we'll never acknowledge Anders and Donal's siblinghood. We can fix that by adding a few more rules:

```
siblings(X, Y) :- brother(X, Y) ; brother(Y, Z).
siblings(X, Y) :- sister(X, Y)  ; sister(Y, X).
```

These rules make brotherhood and sisterhood undirected. Now you get all the results you'd ever want:

```
?- siblings(anders,Y).
Y = brian ;
Y = anders ;
Y = celeste ;
Y = donal ;
Y = brian ;
Y = celeste ;
false.
```

Bet you can figure out how to eliminate the self-siblinghood problem. The other duplicates may turn out to be more troublesome. Give it a shot and let us know if you get stuck.

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your extremely detailed help. I will try this out, and also try to find solutions for the problems you mention. I'm not really into prolog, but it's nice to have a basic understanding for the paradigm this language family uses.

Comment: @Anders Sounds good. Do come back if you run into other problems. I would note that there are really only a handful of languages in the logic paradigm; if Prolog doesn't suit you, take a gander at Mercury, which does have tabling support. You may find it more to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

that's [*transitive closure*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_closure) you want:

```
sibl(A,B):- brother(A,B) ; brother(B,A) ; sister(A,B) ; sister(B,A).

sibl_trans(A,B):- sibl(A,B).
sibl_trans(A,B):- sibl(A,C), sibl_trans(C,B).
```

Your definition is like

```
sibl_trans(A,B):- sibl(A,B).
sibl_trans(A,B):- sibl_trans(A,C), sibl_trans(C,B).
```

This is [*left recursion*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion). Not good, with [*depth-first search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) of Prolog. *Could* work with [*iterative deepening*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search).

This question comes up very frequently.

Comment: Thank you Will, I see your point and will do some trial and errors with it to fully understand and get familiar. I've already given away the points for correct answer, but I'll of course give you a vote up!